# Is there anyway to uncompress and view a standalone .nib to view it in IB?

Tags: ios, xcode

If you view the package contents of IOS apps in iTunes you can see the .nibs in there.

Is there any way of uncompresssing and converting them to .xibs, or loading/viewing them in IB to help get an idea how certain aspects of app's UIs are c